Comboboxs cruzados
Les consulto sobre un particular.
Tengo dos combobox independientes entre sí:
combo1 = ttk.Combobox(values=["A", "B", "C", "D"]) y 
combo2 = ttk.Combobox(values=["1", "2"])

y debo generar un precio que vincule "x" elemento del combo1 con "y" elemento del combo2. (Ej: a-1 = $xxx; a-2 = $yyyy; c-2 = $zzzz).
Intenté creando dos tablas, una para cada combo, y luego vinculando el combo1 con el combo2, de manera que al seleccionar un elemento del combo1, me trajera (vía comboboxselected) los valores del combo2, y que un nuevo comboboxselected aplicado al combo2 me trajera el precio. Pero resulta que la función que trae el precio debería estar leyendo el mismo de ¿una tercer tabla que contenga las combinaciones? Me hace ruido esta solución, porque me parece redundante (aunque quizás sea la manera correcta de hacerlo). Además me genera el problema de que, al agregar un elemento en alguno de los dos combos, se debería actualizar no sólo la tabla correspondiente al combo en cuestión sino también la tercer tabla con la combinación que da por resultado el precio final (para la cual habría que crear las combinaciones a mano).
Me enredé en este lío, quizás le esté pifiando al enfoque de la solución.
Les pido si me esclarecen un poco.
Gracias.

Hola Diego, creo que falta algo más de contexto para poder ayudar. Por ejemplo, mencionas que usas "tablas" para almacenar los datos, pero ¿que estructura son exactamente? ¿tablas en una BD? ¿tablas de Pandas?, ¿diccionarios enlazados?... Por otro lado ¿qué relación existe entre los datos de ambos comboboxes? Un ejemplo sería que combo1 tuviera los nombres de los items y el combo2 el número a comprar y quisieras calcular el precio final (precio_unitario_producto x número_de_artículos).

Dependiendo de la relación entre los datos puede que no necesites ninguna información adicional almacenada para calcular el precio, que necesites almacenar algunas constantes como el precio unitario como en el ejemplo anterior y calcular el precio en tiempo de ejecución, que necesites almacenar el precio de cada combinación de antemano porque no existe una relación matemática entre ambos (por ejemplo, si el combo1 almacena productos y el combo2 vendedores y necesitas mostrar el precio de un producto dado que ofrece un vendedor concreto), etc

Hola FJSevilla. Son tablas de sqlite y los combos son independientes. A ver, por caso, tienes "vehículo" en una tabla y "color" en otra. El precio final sería la combinación del vehículo (no es lo mismo un auto que un camión) y color (no es lo mismo el blanco, que el negro). La combinación de ambos, daría el precio final.

Hola @Diego sería bueno que compartieras el código y/o un ejemplo reproducible.
